# Effect(s) of reset/power glitch/brownout on SAMD20/KL17Z Flash erase/write?

Tags: microcontroller, microchip, flash, nxp

EDIT: I've shortened the initial post since there were too many irrelevant details.

We're using PCBs with an Atmel ATSAMD20E17 and an NXP MKL17Z128VFM4 (heterogeneous redundancy). A system cosists of [1..16] such PCBs connected to a shared power and control/communication cable (24V, ground, 2 control/communication lines).

On both processors our Flash memory map is as follows:

- 0x00000000 - 0x00003FFF : Bootloader
- 0x00004000 - 0x00009FFF : Firmware
- 0x0000A000 - 0x0000FFFF : Data (configuration info, diagnostic logging, etc.)

When changing the setup i.e. exchanging/adding/removing PCBs, there's a configuration phase during which the bootlooder updates some information in the Flash region "Data" (Flash row/sector erase followed by write operation).

We had a few instances in which the bootloader did not work anymore after such an update of the Data region. Since the security bit is set on both processors, we can't read out the Flash memory via SWD and check what has changed in Flash memory when the problem arises.
It is still possible, however, to flash the bootloader again via SWD after encountering the problem, so there's seemingly no physical damage to the processors.

Now for the question:
Is it possible that an ongoing Flash erase/write operation in our Data region goes "haywire" and messes up the Bootloader region (or configuration fuse bits) if there were a brownout or similar supply voltage glitch, or a reset (via the reset pin) e.g. due to a cabling problem?

Any hint is helpful.

Cheers,
Peter.

Comment: Yes of course it is possible and you need to consider such during design. It's common to provide a bulk/backup cap that will hold the MCU supply long enough for flashing to finish. MCU clock disturbances will also mess up flashing. Use CRC in case data integrity matters.

Comment: Btw for high integrity/mission critical software it is custom to store all such data in two "mirror segments" so that you always have at least one valid data set and can revert to one of them in case the other goes corrupt.

Comment: @Lundin: thanks for your feedback!

I'm aware of the fact that a power-out during a Flash write/erase opertaion can result in a corruption of the Flash row/sector in which the operation is going on, but not that it can also impact the rest of the Flash block (as far as I know both processors that we're using have only one Flash block).

Personally, I'd have prefered an external serial EEPROM/Flash for storing this information, but some design decisions were taken "before my time".

Cheers,
Peter.

Comment: External or internal doesn't matter, both have the same problem during power loss. Except external memories might not have the same brown-out protection as a MCU and are therefore even more prone to get corrupt. The main difference otherwise, is that external are way more expensive and also much more vulnerable to EMI. The only advantage of using external memories is that you can place them on a separate removable PCB and that's pretty much the only reason why you'd ever use external memories in the year 2022. Or in case you run out of internal memory, of course.